# fast way to make class for anonyomus class

Tags: c#, linq

In LINQ, if I select some columns from a join "query", I will make a struct to hold the result so that I can use it in making BindingList, parameter passing in different functions. If number of fields is small, it is ok to do manually, but if number of fields is few dozen, it is time consuming. Is there any fast method or tools to convert the LINQ result to class ?

I convert the LINQ to normal SQL and run in SSMS and then convert the result manually.

for example

```
public class CustResult
{
    public string custname {get;set;}
    public string company {get;set;} 
}

var query = (
    from a in db.Cust 
    where a.ID < 10 
    select new CustResult() {
      custname = a.custname,
      company = a.company});

CustResult[] custs = query.ToArray();
```

As you see in the code, the custs variable is a class I can manipulate to do parameter passing, the fields inside are well known by compiler.

Comment: If you have more than a handful of these mappings, best candidate is using `Automapper`  http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html

Answer (score 4):

Add a constructor for the subtype that takes the base type as parameter, so you only have to do it once.

```
public class CustResult
{
    public string custname {get;set;}
    public string company {get;set;} 

    public CustResult(Cust cust)
    {
        this.custname = cust.custname;
        this.company = cust.company;
    }
}
```

A more succinct way would be to add a conversion operator

```
public static implicit operator CustResult(Cust cust)
{
    return new CustResult()
    {
        custname = cust.custname,
        company = cust.company
    }
}
```

Just be aware of which parts will be run directly as SQL as SQL doesn't support these conversions naturally, so it won't be appropriate 100% of the time.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. My query is not that is not that simple. It does not have an object class to hold it. You may think that I have three table to join, i take 5 columns from each table to make the result. In this case, do i make a constructor to have 3 parameters ?

Comment: Yes, exactly, that's what DTO's are for. Just keep them seperate from your objects that directly represent how your data is stored.